# Checking all fields are validated successfully through buttonclick in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

In my Windows form I have a `Button` called Save.  When I click on that button, data should be saved to database if all fields in the form are validated successfully.  Otherwise, an error message should be displayed.

I have tried:

```
private void btnNotesSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ValidateChildren(ValidationConstraints.None))
    {
        DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
        dr[0] = txtName.Text;
        dr[1] = txtPersonResponsible.Text;
        dr[2] = txtPersonResponsibleIDDetails.Text;
        dr[3] = txtAlternativePersonResponsible.Text;
        dr[4] = txtAlternativePersonResponsibleIDDetails.Text;
        dr[5] = txtCompanyRegNo.Text;
        dr[6] = txtVatNo.Text;
        dr[7] = txtPremiseNo.Text;
        dr[8] = txtStreetName1.Text;
        dr[9] = txtStreetName2.Text;
        dr[10] = txtSubUrb.Text;
        dr[11] = txtCity.Text;
        dr[12] = txtProvince.Text;
        dr[13] = txtCountry.Text;
        dr[14] = txtPinCode.Text;
        dr[15] = txtPostalPremiseNo.Text;
        dr[16] = txtPostalStreetName1.Text;
        dr[17] = txtPostalStreetName2.Text;
        dr[18] = txtPostalSubUrb.Text;
        dr[19] = txtPostalCity.Text;
        dr[20] = txtPostalProvince.Text;
        dr[21] = txtPostalCountry.Text;
        dr[22] = txtPostalPinCode.Text;
        dr[23] = txtTelephone1.Text;
        dr[24] = txtTelephone2.Text;
        dr[25] = txtMobile1.Text;
        dr[26] = txtMobile2.Text;
        dr[27] = txtFax1.Text;
        dr[28] = txtFax2.Text;
        dr[29] = txtEmail1.Text;
        dr[30] = txtEmail2.Text;
        dr[31] = txtWebsite.Text;
        dr[32] = txtWorkingHours.Text;
        dr[33] = txtAccountHolderName.Text;
        dr[34] = txtBankName.Text;
        dr[35] = txtAccountType.Text;
        dr[36] = txtAccountNumber.Text;
        dr[37] = txtBranchCode.Text;
        dr[38] = rtxtBanking.Text;
        dr[39] = txtCreditLimit.Text;
        dr[40] = txtStartingDate.Text;
        dr[41] = txtEndingDate.Text;
        dr[42] = lstFinance.Text;
        dr[43] = rtxtFinance.Text;
        dr[44] = rtxtNotes.Text;
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
        cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        da.Update(ds, "CompanyDetails");
        MessageBox.Show("data saved to DB");
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("please fill all mandatory fields");
}
```

But this is not working.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: How is it "not working"?  When stepping through the debugger, on what line does the observed behavior differ from the expected behavior?  What are the runtime values when this happens?

Comment: Add an ErrorProvider component from your toolbox and then go from there. Here is a how-to from the codeproject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/898/How-To-Use-The-ErrorProvider-Object-To-Indicate-In HTH

Comment: i have already added errorprovider...

Comment: I would suggest to look at the article I posted from codeproject.

Comment: i had a look at your article but it doesn't solve my prob.. i used VS2012 framework for defining the validations, i don't have any events like validating and validated in my code block.. as of know with the above code i just only getting errors, but my need is without validation the data shouldn't be saved to database, so that i used button_click to validate all fields but i couldn't.....